# wordpress tag link by tag name in a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to get the permalink of a specified tag by it's name in the Wordpress shortcode function, the shortcode look like so:

```php
function shortcode_hashtag($attr, $content){
  $tagId = get_term_by('name', do_shortcode($content), 'tag');
  return '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tagId).'" title="">'.do_shortcode($content).'</a>';
}

add_shortcode('hash', 'shortcode_hashtag');
```

the output link is the link of the post itself and not the tag permalink

Comment: What's your question? Does the above code not work or is there something else you're looking for?

Comment: It's not working, the output link is the link of the post itself and not the tag permalink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of [do_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) seems to be wrong.

Try this instead?

```
function shortcode_hashtag($atts, $content) {
  $tag = get_term_by('name', $content, 'post_tag');
  $tag_id = $tag->term_id;
  $tag_permalink = get_tag_link($tag_id);
  return '<a href="' . $tag_permalink . '">' . $content . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'hash', 'shortcode_hashtag' );
```